# How to represent the relationship between an instance of a class and the class that gets it as an input?

Tags: python, class, uml, class-diagram

I have a class called `House`. The instance of this class is `house`.

```py
class House:
    def __init__(self, height, length):
        self.height = height
        self.length = length

    def housePlan():
        houseHeight = self.height
        houseEdgeLength = self.length

house = House(height,length)
```

I have another class called `Person`. This class gets several inputs including an instance of `House`.

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name, house):
        self.name = name
        self.house = house
```

Question Edit: I would like to present my program to an audiance, how I can present these relationships with diagrams?

Comment: Structural or Behavioral?

Comment: @wwii if you can provide for both I'll be grateful.

Comment: Class diagrams basically are meant to show classes, not instances. Though it's possible to mix per UML spec, but why?

Comment: You're right. Then my question is if I would like to present my program, how can present these relationships using diagrams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have another class called Person. This class gets several inputs including an instance of House

the instance of *House* is not only given in argument of the constructor of *Person* but it is a property of the class (`self.house = house`), so :

[image]

I said *name* is a *String* which is very probable.

All attributes / property / operations are public to respect Python rules.

At the level of a class diagram it is not possible to see from where the arguments of the operation come from, for that you can use an interaction (e.g. a sequence diagram like in your next question where I also put an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66939295/2458991)) or an activity

(Out of that it is strange your house has a length but not a width, so it is mandatory a square)

Comment: Thank you very much again @bruno! Again it's a toy example and yes having no width makes no sense.

Comment: @bruno hey, what software have you used to make this diagram?

Answer (score 2):

Still, there are many ways to present what you have. Anyhow, here's a viable way.

Basically you should show just the static classes in a class diagram. That shows how they are related. Since there are only `House` and `Person` it should not be difficult to sketch them on a single diagram. When things get more complex you might need more diagrams to show sub-domains.

Now the "input" part of the question: Here it's just best to create a [sequence diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html) to show how instances are created and passed around in parameters of messages. In order to show different scenarios you would create an extra SD per scenario. You should not overdo it with details. That is: avoid graphical programming! Just show enough to get a good overview.

It would be possible to show instances and classes semi-statically on a single object/class diagram. But that rarely makes sense. So you should just go with a SD as stated above.