# How to show the relationship between a class and another class that takes the instance of the class's instance as an input with a sequence diagram?

Tags: python, class, uml, class-diagram, sequence-diagram

I will use the same example from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66934927/how-to-represent-the-relationship-between-an-instance-of-a-class-and-the-class-t) and modify it.

I have a class called `House`. The instance of this class is `house`.

```py
class House:
    def __init__(self, steel, money):
        self.steel = steel
        self.money = money

    def housePlan():
        houseHeight = self.steel/self.money
        houseEdgeLength = self.money
```

I have another class called `Person`. This class gets several inputs and creates an instance of `House`. **`House` can exist without the `Person` class.**

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name, steel, money):
        self.name = name
        self.steel = steel
        self.money = money
   
    def buildHouse():
        house = House(self.steel, self.money)
```

How can I show the relationship between these two classes with UML sequence diagrams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I show the relationship between these two classes with UML sequence diagrams?

The goal of a *Sequence Diagram* is not to show relationships between classes, a *Sequence Diagram* describes an *Interaction* by focusing on the sequence of *Messages* that are exchanged, along with their corresponding *OccurrenceSpecifications* on the *Lifelines* ([formal/2017-12-05](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1) § *17.8 Sequence Diagrams*)

From your code *buildHouse* creates a new instance of *House* so there is an *object creation Message*. Because *house* is a local variable the instance is immediately lost and then we can consider it is immediately deleted by the garbage collector of Python, so a *DestructionOccurrenceSpecification* depicted by a cross in the form of an X at the bottom of a Lifeline (§ *17.4.4.2 DestructionOccurrenceSpecification*).

[image]

(I used a *found message* for *buildHouse* because the caller is unknown nor relevant in your question)

> House can exist without the Person class

If you speak about the class, yes for sure because *House* definition is not nested in *Person*.

If you globally speak about instances, there is nothing saying only a *Person* can instantiate a *House* so yes too.

If you refer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66934927/2458991) in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66939532/2458991) I do not use a *composition* so the deletion of an instance of *Person* does not imply the deletion of the associated instance of *House*.

But again in *buildHouse* the new instance of *House* is immediately lost because not returned nor saved in a global variable nor saved in an attribute of *Person*, and then will be deleted by the garbage

Comment: Thank you very much @bruno! This was just a toy example and I understand the logic to implement it on my complex architecture. Yes, in this example house will be deleted by the garbage collector.